# Disable autocommit in SQL Developer when using MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, autocommit

I'd like to connect to a MySQL server with Oracle SQL Developer, but with autocommit disabled. By default, all MySQL connections have autocommit enabled, which is rather odd.

The global setting in SQL Developer is unchecked, and

```
set autocommit=0;
```

results in the error

> set autocommit script command forced off, as connection level autocommit is on.

In the connection's settings are no other options besides hostname, port and a drop down box for database selection.

I'm using SQL Developer 3.2.10 with latest JDBC connector, 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will run into an error if you try and use

```
start transaction;

-- Your SQL statements

commit;
```

...out of the box on a MySQL database in SQLDeveloper (as Michael mentioned in a comment to another answer.)

In order to get around this error that Michael referenced in his comment you can use the following hint:

```
/*sqldev:stmt*/start transaction;

-- Your SQL statements

/*sqldev:stmt*/commit;
```

Found this information [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2205731).

Answer (score 13):

In Oracle SQL Developer **4** the setting has moved:

> Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced > Autocommit

Default is off.

Alternative:

```
set autocommit off;
```

Comment: This setting is ignored when you're using MySQL database, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the auto commit option in SqlDeveloper. Go to Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> ObjectViewer Parameters and uncheck the box Set Auto Commit On.

Comment: `Can't call rollback when autocommit=true` :-)

Answer (score 0):

enclose the commands with 'start transaction' and 'commit'. mysql turned off auto-commit on 'start transaction' until 'commit' or 'rollback' is issued

Comment: This will end in an error: `Error starting at line 1 in command:
START TRANSACTION
Error report:
Unable to open file: "TRANSACTION.sql"`

Answer (score 0):

Outils-->Preferences-->Fenetre SQL--> Validation automatique de transactions SQL
uncheck the check box

Comment: Nope, this does not toggle autocommit on MySQL connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on AutoCommit by
clicking on Tools | Preferences
Open the Database Tree
select Worksheet parameters
Check on the Autocommit in SQL Worksheet box

Answer (score 0):

```
set autocommit=false;--or true
--comment required/**/
/*sqldev:stmt*/start transaction; 
--your sql
/*sqldev:stmt*/commit;
/*sqldev:stmt*/rollback;
```

Answer (score -1):

connect sqlplus as sysadmin and type command "SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF" it is off as command.
and if u want to check it is off or not the type command "show autocommit" and it show like
"autocommit OFF"

Comment: This question relates to Oracle SQL Developer that connects to a MySQL database. No sqlplus involved.